# Django session data not saving

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to add data variables to a session object but the data is not saving.

My views.py:

```
def addToCart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        print product_id
        print request.session

        try:
            cart = request.session['cart']
            print "cart : " + cart
            cart.append(product_id)
            request.session['cart'] = cart
        except:
            print "no session data"
            cart = []
            cart.append(product_id)
            request.session['cart'] = cart

        request.session.save()

        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'Added To Cart Successfully !!!'

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"result": "Failure !!!"}),content_type="application/json")
```

I can see a session object when I run `print request.session` but my data is not being saved. Every time my view is called it returns this:

```
1
<django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x03D62790>
no session data
[21/Nov/2015 11:07:53] "POST /add_to_cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 44
1
<django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x03D512F0>
no session data
[21/Nov/2015 11:07:57] "POST /add_to_cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 44
```

Here `1` is my `product_id`. It always print no session data.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I added the complete view method. I am using ajax call to save data.

Comment: Could you provide the complete code of the view function?

Comment: It should be saved in your `except` block - have you checked at the end of that block what it contains? A couple of other points: blanket catching exceptions is never a good idea and will make your code a nightmare to debug. Secondly, there is no need to explicitly `save()` the session.

Comment: By default, session values are automatically saved when modified. You don't need to call `save()` method. Also, try clearing your browser cookies and run your webapp.

Comment: Are you sure you need to re-assign `cart`? Lists are mutable,  you already appended to `cart`

Comment: I read somewhere that you cannot directly append to list in session..so i created an instance of list and appended the modified list to session variable.

Comment: Don't ever, ever use a blank except. Something is probably going wrong inside your try block, but we can't know what it is because you catch all errors. Don't do that: catch the KeyError only.